# Cannot interpret token '.' at position 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, datatable

I have a textbox and a calendar extender, here's the code in page Default.aspx:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="tbdate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

 <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="tbdate" 
      Format="dd.MM.yyyy">
 </asp:CalendarExtender>
```

Now in Default.aspx.cs page I try to insert the value from the TextBox in new columns from DataTable

```
 dt.Columns.Add("date", typeof(string), tbdate.Text);
```

and I have this error

Cannot interpret token '.' at position 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you don't want to add this date-value as `DataColumn`   but as `DataRow`:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("date", typeof(DateTime));
dt.Rows.Add(DateTime.Parse(tbdate.Text));
```

By the way, the overload of [`DataColumnCollection.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/632cdz7z.aspx) that you've used is for an [`Expression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx).

If you want to add this value to all rows:

```
var selectedDate = DateTime.Parse(tbdate.Text));
dt.Columns.Add("date", typeof(DateTime));
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    row["date"] = selectedDate;
}
```

Comment: I want to add this value in a new column for all rows

Comment: @Alex: Edited my answer to clarify my approach.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your column first :

```
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("date", typeof(DateTime));
```

then do a loop and add the required date:

```
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
 row["date"] = DateTime.Parse(tbdate.Text);
}
```

Comment: foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
 /*maybe?*/ row["date"] = tbdate.Text;
}

Comment: again Error String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.Couldn't store <19.04.2012> in datelesson Column.  Expected type is DateTime.

Comment: @Sam1: I don't see the difference to my answer apart from being posted 15 minutes later ;)

Comment: @TimSchmelter i think i posted the loop before you but forgot the parse in loop :)